# How to identify and convert a series of numbers in DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I need to identify the values in a field which are of 9 series and greater than or equal to 99999 and convert them to 0s in DataStage i.e atleast first 5bytes of the field are 9s. Here are some examples to explain the situation better
999.00 - Don't convert
9999.00- Don't convert
99999.00- Convert to 0
999991.00-Convert to 0
100000.00- Don't convert
999999.00- Convert to 0
123456.00-Don't convert
9999999.00-Convert to 0
1999999.00-Don't convert
1000000.00-Don't convert

Right now i have If Convert('9','', Trim(Trim(Field(NullToZero(AMT),'.',1)),'0','L')) = ''  Then 0. This converts any 9s but our goal is to convert 9s of 99999 and greater only. Please help with solution

Comment: will this work? If (Trim(Trim(Field(NullToZero(AMT),'.',1)),'0','L')[1,5] ="99999") then 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Field() function to work with just the digits to the left of the decimal placeholder.  Test that this value has at least five characters, and that they are all "9".

```
If Len(Field(AMT,".",1,1) >= 5 And Convert("9","",Field(AMT,".",1,1)) = "" Then 0 Else AMT
```

Even better would be to resolve the Field() function into a stage variable, so that it's not executed twice, and use that stage variable in the expression.

Comment: I am trying with Left(Field(AMT, “.”, 1),5)=“99999”, since we need to check if the first 5 bytes are 9s. Will check your solution too. Thanks

Comment: what is the additional parameter in field function? so far i have used field (col, delimiter, 1) but never seen that additional 1 you have used in the field function. what it does? could you please explain?

Comment: Use the Knowledge Center for syntax questions.  In this case https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-field-function